# Convolution Basics

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

My Doubt is very Basic.
Suppose we are given a 3 channel Image and a Filter of say 2*2 and we have 6 such filters.
1. We take a filter slide it over the image to calculate the dot product at every spatial location. My Doubt is:-

When one filter is dot product with the input image. Its dot product is calculated for entire 3 channels right?

When we get an activation map. Is that the map corresponding to the result of dot product of all three channels or a separate activation map for every channel is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `2 x 2` filter is operated on a 3 channel image, then the shape of each filter will be `2 x 2 x 3`. So when one filter is convolved with the image, the filter will be multiplied with the 3-channel image element-wise and then sum across channels will be performed. So the answer for your first question is yes.

Regarding the activation map, the output of the convolution will have 6 channels since there are 6 filters. So each channel corresponds to the result of dot product of all three channels as mentioned above.

Read [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) to understand these concepts better.